# Download Java 1.7.0 JDK for CentOS

Tags: centos, java, centos-5, openjdk

I have a CentOS 5.2 32-bit machine, which I can't connect to the internet.

As Java Oracle does not seem to work, I would like to try using OpenJDK, but therefore I need to install OpenJDK first (which means that I need to download the binaries first).

On the internet, I have found several places where I can find the source code. I have also found numerous sites which mention the usage of "yum install".

However, as I don't have a connection to the internet I need to have the binaries (e.g. in a rpm package).

Does anybody know where I could find this for my system?

Thanks

Comment: https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-1.7.0-openjdk

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply, David. I've upvoted your comment as this site contains quite some interesting RPM packages. Unfortunately I have already visited this site, and the only RPM I found which looked useful was "java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el5_10.i386.rpm". I have tried to install this but I ended up with the error message that some other files are missing: `error: Failed dependencies:
        libgif.so.4 is needed by java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65-2.5.1.2.el5_10.i386
        tzdata-java is needed by <idem>`

I prefer not to end up in a cascade of failing dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Download OpenJDK:**

i.e. from [RPMFind](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=java-1.7.0-openjdk) (as notice @DavidPostill)

**2. Transfer via Flash drive \ [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/) \ SCP \ SFTP to VM and install**

`yum -y install path-to-your-rpm-file`

or

`rpm -ivh path-to-rpm`

**3. Test java version:**

`java -version`

If you needed you can switch java version with

`alternatives --config java`

Comment: Thanks for the information. Meanwhile my problems are solved. Just one remark: I had forgotten to mention that the CentOS is not a real machine, but a virtual one, located on my PC. In order to do the file transfer, I'm working with a mounting point, referring to my PC.